# Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted

Tags: php, laravel, gmail

I recently encountered a SwiftMail error while trying to send a mail through gmail.

```
 Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.
```

I was trying to  send mail through my gmail and google thought that I was a spam(maybe because I was requesting too fast) I received a mail from them saying my account was access and I told them it was me. I was able to send mail without problem and it just occured now.

This is the contents of my env file.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=talentscoutphil@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypasswordhere
MAIL_FROM=talentscoutphil@gmail.com
MAIL_NAME=talentscout
```

Answer (score 239, accepted):

I researched on the internet and some answers includes enabling the "**access for lesser app**" and "**unlocking gmail captcha**" which sadly didn't work for me until I found the 2-step verification.

**What I did the following was:**

1. enable the **2-step verification** to google [HERE](https://www.google.com/landing/2step/)
2. Create App Password to be use by your system [HERE](https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords)
3. I selected *Others (custom name)* and clicked generate
4. Went to my env file in laravel and edited this

   MAIL_USERNAME=talentscoutphil@gmail.com

   MAIL_PASSWORD=thepasswordgenerated
5. Restarted my apache server and boom! **It works again**.

This was my solution. I created this to atleast make other people not go wasting their time researching for a possible answer.

Comment: I follow step by step but can't get it working. Please share your other variables (for example encryption, port).

Comment: I answer to myself. Encryption `tls`, port `587`. But most importantly: `php artisan config:cache` to update the env variables!

Comment: for me it just worked by disabling **2-step verification**

Comment: plus 1 for the answer. It's working on `yii2` aswell

Comment: You got +1, Worked on Laravel 5.5.

Comment: I did exactly these steps and solved my problem. After using app password, I disabled 2 step verification, and it still works.

Comment: @Imtiaz Although it still works, I prefer it to be enabled for security purposes. Glad that it worked though!

Comment: Hello not need these steps, you can execute php artisan config:cache
All is well. Best.

Comment: Updated Gmail security options to the lowest possible and it fixed the issue.

Comment: does this thing work when i am trying with an gsuite account?

Comment: worked perfectly fine without apache restart

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem, changing my gmail password fixed the issue, and also don't forget to enable [less secure app on on your gmail account](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1)

Comment: That's great! It seems we differ on our solutions but atleast you got it working!

Comment: This was enough for me! Thanks :)

Answer (score 11):

i had same issue i resolve this use under

go to gmail.com

my account

and enable

Allow less secure apps: ON

it start works

Comment: Work for me in Symfony 4.3 . The error was: app.ERROR: Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "xxxxxx" using 2 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN ...........  Username and Password not accepted.

Answer (score 4):

I had everything fine. Less secure app option was also enabled. Still, I was getting the error. What I have done is:

- Google will send you **Critical security alert**
- Then you have to authorize that activity. ( Clicking on '**YES, THAT WAS ME**' type thing )
- Then you can try sending email again.

Answer (score 3):

From May 30, 2022, ​​Google no longer supports the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and password.

Important: This deadline does not apply to Google Workspace or Google Cloud Identity customers. The enforcement date for these customers will be announced on the Workspace blog at a later date.

For more information, continue to read.
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en&visit_id=637919157823422324-2612210762&p=less-secure-apps&rd=1

Answer (score 2):

This single step worked for me... No 2-step verification.
As I had created a dummy account for my local development, so I was OK with this setting.
Make sure you only do this if your account contains NO personal or any critical data.
This is just another way of tackling this error and NOT secure.

I turned ON the setting to alow less secured apps to be allowed access.
Form here : 
https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Comment: Work for me in Symfony 4.3 . The error was: app.ERROR: Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "xxxxxx" using 2 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN ...........  Username and Password not accepted.

Answer (score 2):

This is my .env mail settings

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=example@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=hello27
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

i was getting thesame error as stated in the question but by using

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Everything worked fine

Answer (score 2):

Gmail tends to block usage of mailing addresses which are being used in other applications as username for security reasons. Either you should create a new email address for mail purpose or you must go to the Less Secure App Access and turn on the access for less secure apps. Gmail will send you a mail for confirmation from where you can verify that those changes were made by yourself. Only then, you can use such mailing addresses for mailing purpose through applications.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to update anything in **config/mail.php**. just put you credential in **.env** with this specific key's. This is my **.env** file.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=example@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

I had the same issue after long time debugging and googling i have found the solution. that by enabling less secure apps. the email started working.

if your gmail is secure with 2 step verification you can't enable less secure app. so turn off 2 step verification and enable less secure app. by click here [enable less secure apps on your gmail account](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, then I did this two steps:

- Enable "Allow less secure apps" on your google account security policy.
- Restart your local servers.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue and solved it with no 2FA enabled ("Allow less secure apps" is still in need).

After checking [Google error code list](https://support.google.com/a/answer/3726730), I thought maybe there are some errors in `.env`.

Below settings are tested in Laravel 8 and worked:

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=username@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD='your#password_here'  # put the password in quotes
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=username@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Please remember that **put the password in quotes**. That works for me.

Comment: The password in quotes worked, you also need to do the following:
`php artisan config: cache`

Answer (score 1):

If your using your cpanel custom email, change your host from smtp.gmail.com to your domain name. it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

As from May 30, 2022 Google has stopped  the support of third-party apps or devices which ask you to signin to your Google Account using only your username and password.

To solve this,

1. make sure you that you have enabled 2-step verification.
2. Then select App paswords.
3. select app and device you want to generate the app password for.
4. on select app select mail then on device choose and name a custom device.
5. After that, a password will be generated for you to use. Replace your original password with the generated password. Refresh or upload your files to the server the reload.
   It will work

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. first checked the credentials and username, they were all good, then restarted my server (docker stop/start) and it works now. something with cache I believe