# Configuring Emails in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, swiftmailer, laravel-mail

I am trying to setup emails in my Laravel aplication, I have my env file something like this:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=noreply@xxx.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

I tried according to the answer given in this question [Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42558903/expected-response-code-250-but-got-code-535-with-message-535-5-7-8-username)

I followed the steps, enabled 2 step verification, then created app password and configured my `.env` file

Finally I did `php artisan config:cache`

> Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "noreply@xxx.com" using 3 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Swift_TransportException: Expected response code 235 but got code "534", with message "534-5.7.14

Please help me out with this. Thanks.

Comment: So your authentication failed, how do you think we can help?

Comment: @Daan I followed the steps, before that I was using normal mail password, but that didn't workout, I am sure there no mistake with my credentials.

Comment: set less secure app in your google account setting

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta you mean disable 2 step verification and enable less secure app?

Comment: noreply@xxx.com is a gmail adress you own right?

Comment: yes @NitishKumar

Comment: enable less secure app as well 2 step verification also.

Comment: @Christoffer yes I have purchased GMail for my domain, I can go to gmail and login with the credentials.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42558903/expected-response-code-250-but-got-code-535-with-message-535-5-7-8-username

Comment: @PayalPandav I have already mentioned the same link in the question.

Comment: did you try using ssl encryption and port 465 also?

Comment: @Christoffer no, you mean to say `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl` and `MAIL_PORT=465` ??

Comment: @NitishKumar yes

Comment: you want to different reply to..?

Comment: @Christoffer Same issue, no change. :(

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42558903/expected-response-code-250-but-got-code-535-with-message-535-5-7-8-username maybe help you

Comment: @Madhusudan I already have same link in my question. I followed the same thing.

Answer (score 7):

Steps to configure Gmail/Google SMTP with Laravel

1. `.env` file setup

   ```
    MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
    MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
    MAIL_PORT=465
    MAIL_USERNAME=GMAIL_USERNAME
    MAIL_PASSWORD=GMAIL_PASSWORD
    MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
   ```
2. Allow Less Secure Apps

> Go to Google Accounts > Security > Allow less secure apps.

3. Allow new device, either allow new signing from google review notification from your mobile device or if that doesn't work. Login with the same gmail id and open below link, it will enable you to allow the recent login attempt. (only required once to authenticate our Laravel app)

> https://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

**P.S.** - If you have 2 step verification enabled, then Create app password and use that instead of `GMAIL_PASSWORD`

Reference - https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229

Comment: This `UnlockCaptcha` saved my day. Thx.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. It was the Captcha link that fixed the issue, even though I don't use it. It seems there is an additional step to allow new devices to open the gmail account.

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?visit_id=636865986363810933-1186759849&rd=1#cantsignin

I had already set up this below beforehand

Allow less secure apps: If you don't use 2-Step Verification, you might need to allow less secure apps to access your account.

Comment: Thank you, @Paul Mead. I just follow your given URL. It works like charm.

Comment: thanks the url that work for me is https://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Answer (score 4):

> Need to create new `less secure` gmail account for configuration `Email`. your email should `not use in more than 3 projects`.

Comment: This type of answer should be in a comment.

Comment: I tried to using with different emails. But it always give me the same error "Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "" using 3 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "534", with message "534-5.7.14"

Answer (score 2):

If you can't solve this with all the answers above, go to your account setting https://myaccount.google.com/security turn on two-step verification and generate an app password, this way will definitely work.

Comment: super!! that worked.. thanks a lot, I was trying to solve this issue since a month and your answer worked just in 10 minutes... thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use  **MAIL_PASSWORD=yourapppassword** instead of gmail password
like

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
 MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
 MAIL_PORT=465
 MAIL_USERNAME=GMAIL_USERNAME
 MAIL_PASSWORD=APP_PASSWORD
 MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

If u are not created. Create a new one
go to Google Account ,then security then u will app password.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32282345)

Answer (score 0):

use app password instead of gmail password
go to gmail settings/security
In Signing in to Google section
open app password and generate password