# Email sending problem in server (Laravel 5.6)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.6. I am trying to send email from my application. It's working fine from my local pc. But when I tried from server it showes error. **Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "xyz@gmail.com" using 3 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Swift_TransportException: Expected response code 235 but got code "534", with message "534-5.7.14**

I am using subdomain .
My .env file is

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=xyz@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=************
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

I also did

- config:clear
- view:clear
- config:cache
- Allowed less secure apps: ON

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you use an app password?

Comment: I used email and it's password

Comment: https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords it is possible that you need an dedicated app password for your gmail account on your server.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52985313/configuring-emails-in-laravel

Comment: Thanks a lot @greenhalos . It's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the solution was to create an app-password for the gmail account: https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords

Answer (score 0):

Try using mail.goole.com or googlemail.gmail.com instead of mail.gmail.com