# Sending email using nodemailer not working

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I have this sendMail cloud function here through i am trying to send a simple email. I am not sure what is the mistake i am doing but i keep getting `400 Bad request` error on postman whenever i hit this function.
P.S i am adding correct credentials of my gmail account too

Here is my cloud function

const functions = require('firebase-functions');

```
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
    service: 'Gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'abc@gmail.com',
        pass: '12345'
    }
}));


//Send email
exports.sendMail = functions.https.onRequest((request, responde) => {
    // cors(req, res, () => {    
        // getting dest email by query string
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET', 'POST');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    if(req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.end();
    }
    else
    {
        if(req.body.dest != null || req.body.dest != undefined) {
            const dest = req.query.dest;

            const mailOptions = {
                from: 'Ehsan Nisar <ABC@gmail.com>',
                to: dest,
                subject: 'I\'M A PICKLE!!!', // email subject
                html: `<p style="font-size: 16px;">Pickle Riiiiiiiiiiiiiiiick!!</p>
                    <br />
                    <img src="https://images.prod.meredith.com/product/fc8754735c8a9b4aebb786278e7265a5/1538025388228/l/rick-and-morty-pickle-rick-sticker" />
                ` // email content in HTML
            };

            // returning result
            return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (erro, info) => {
                if(erro){
                    return res.send(erro);
                }
                return res.send('Sended');
            });
        }
        else {
            res.send(400, {
                "message": "All fields are required"
            })
        }
    // });  
    }  
});
```

Comment: Could you please add your postman request? Looking at your code, it seems that in the request req.body.dest is either null or undefined.

Comment: `All fields are required`

Comment: @hoangdv try with `req.query.dest` and provide your own credentials. its a post call

Comment: @LucasDeAngelis yes it was nulified and i have changed it to `req.query.dest` but now postman is giving me 200 but showing this response
 
`{
    "code": "EAUTH",
    "response": "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials x64sm1393872ill.75 - gsmtp",
    "responseCode": 535,
    "command": "AUTH PLAIN"
}`

Comment: my credentails are correct

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42558903/expected-response-code-250-but-got-code-535-with-message-535-5-7-8-username

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42558903/expected-response-code-250-but-got-code-535-with-message-535-5-7-8-username)