# Site built on Laravel, when I am submitting form the smtp error is appears

Tags: php, laravel, smtp, gmail

Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "myname@gmail.com" using 3 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials b11sm6858122pjz.54 - gsmtp ". Authenticator PLAIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials b11sm6858122pjz.54 - gsmtp ". Authenticator XOAUTH2 returned Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials b11sm6858122pjz.54 - gsmtp ".

Comment: Check .env file and put correct mailing server details.

Comment: Thanks @PankajVerma, I am using gmail, and the mailing details are correct.

Comment: As per the error log, the email credentials are not correct, I think.

Comment: @PankajVerma, Thanks, but with same credentials contact form is working, but download pdf with submitting form not working.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42558903/expected-response-code-250-but-got-code-535-with-message-535-5-7-8-username