# Laravel - Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username using cpanel

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, smtp

I got this error:

#### Swift_TransportException

> Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "noxxxxxx@my-domain.com" using 2 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535 Incorrect authentication data ". Authenticator PLAIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535 Incorrect authentication data ".

and this is my `.environment` : using xxxx for anonimity.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.my-domain.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=noxxxxxx@my-domain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=my_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=noxxxxxx@my-domain.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

#### Error Logs

```
[2021-03-12 04:33:52] local.ERROR: Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "noxxxxxx@my-domain.com" using 2 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535 Incorrect authentication data
". Authenticator PLAIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535 Incorrect authentication data
". {"exception":"[object] (Swift_TransportException(code: 0): Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username \"noxxxxxx@my-domain.com\" using 2 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code \"535\", with message \"535 Incorrect authentication data
\". Authenticator PLAIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code \"535\", with message \"535 Incorrect authentication data
\". at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\swiftmailer\\swiftmailer\\lib\\classes\\Swift\\Transport\\Esmtp\\AuthHandler.php:191)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\swiftmailer\\swiftmailer\\lib\\classes\\Swift\\Transport\\EsmtpTransport.php(371): Swift_Transport_Esmtp_AuthHandler->afterEhlo(Object(Swift_SmtpTransport))
#1 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\swiftmailer\\swiftmailer\\lib\\classes\\Swift\\Transport\\AbstractSmtpTransport.php(148): Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport->doHeloCommand()
#2 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\swiftmailer\\swiftmailer\\lib\\classes\\Swift\\Mailer.php(65): Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport->start()
#3 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailer.php(488): Swift_Mailer->send(Object(Swift_Message), Array)
#4 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailer.php(261): Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailer->sendSwiftMessage(Object(Swift_Message))
#5 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Notifications\\Channels\\MailChannel.php(65): Illuminate\\Mail\\Mailer->send(Object(Illuminate\\Support\\HtmlString), Array, Object(Closure))
#6 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Notifications\\NotificationSender.php(148): Illuminate\\Notifications\\Channels\\MailChannel->send(Object(App\\User), Object(Illuminate\\Auth\\Notifications\\VerifyEmail))
#7 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Notifications\\NotificationSender.php(106): Illuminate\\Notifications\\NotificationSender->sendToNotifiable(Object(App\\User), '299eac3a-fa57-4...', Object(Illuminate\\Auth\\Notifications\\VerifyEmail), 'mail')
#8 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Support\\Traits\\Localizable.php(19): Illuminate\\Notifications\\NotificationSender->Illuminate\\Notifications\\{closure}()
#9 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Notifications\\NotificationSender.php(109): Illuminate\\Notifications\\NotificationSender->withLocale(NULL, Object(Closure))
#10 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Notifications\\NotificationSender.php(79): Illuminate\\Notifications\\NotificationSender->sendNow(Object(Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Collection), Object(Illuminate\\Auth\\Notifications\\VerifyEmail))
#11 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Notifications\\ChannelManager.php(39): Illuminate\\Notifications\\NotificationSender->send(Object(Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Collection), Object(Illuminate\\Auth\\Notifications\\VerifyEmail))
#12 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Notifications\\RoutesNotifications.php(18): Illuminate\\Notifications\\ChannelManager->send(Object(App\\User), Object(Illuminate\\Auth\\Notifications\\VerifyEmail))
#13 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Auth\\MustVerifyEmail.php(38): App\\User->notify(Object(Illuminate\\Auth\\Notifications\\VerifyEmail))
#14 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Auth\\Listeners\\SendEmailVerificationNotification.php(19): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Auth\\User->sendEmailVerificationNotification()
#15 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Events\\Dispatcher.php(389): Illuminate\\Auth\\Listeners\\SendEmailVerificationNotification->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Auth\\Events\\Registered))
#16 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Events\\Dispatcher.php(218): Illuminate\\Events\\Dispatcher->Illuminate\\Events\\{closure}('Illuminate\\\\Auth...', Array)
#17 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\helpers.php(477): Illuminate\\Events\\Dispatcher->dispatch('Illuminate\\\\Auth...')
#18 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Auth\\RegistersUsers.php(33): event(Object(Illuminate\\Auth\\Events\\Registered))
#19 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller.php(54): App\\Http\\Controllers\\Auth\\RegisterController->register(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#20 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction('register', Array)
#21 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php(219): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(App\\Http\\Controllers\\Auth\\RegisterController), 'register')
#22 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php(176): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#23 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(681): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#24 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(130): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#25 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\app\\Http\\Middleware\\RedirectIfAuthenticated.php(24): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#26 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(171): App\\Http\\Middleware\\RedirectIfAuthenticated->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#27 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#28 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#29 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken.php(78): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#30 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#31 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#32 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#33 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\app\\Http\\Middleware\\LocaleMiddleware.php(26): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#34 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(171): App\\Http\\Middleware\\LocaleMiddleware->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#35 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession.php(56): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#36 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#37 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#38 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#39 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies.php(67): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#40 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#41 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(105): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#42 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(683): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#43 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(658): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#44 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(624): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#45 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(613): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#46 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(170): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#47 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(130): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#48 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\fideloper\\proxy\\src\\TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#49 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(171): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#50 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#51 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#52 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#53 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#54 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#55 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#56 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(63): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#57 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(171): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#58 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(105): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#59 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(145): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#60 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(110): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#61 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\public\\index.php(52): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#62 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\latihan\\jasuko06\\server.php(21): require_once('C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs...')
#63 {main}
"}
```

And what should I do ?

Thanks...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42558903/expected-response-code-250-but-got-code-535-with-message-535-5-7-8-username)

Comment: use MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail MAIL_MAILER=sendmail

Comment: @Chico3001 nah I tried it, but not solve my problem

Comment: @Kamlesh okay sir i'll try it . thanks

Comment: @sd007 okay sir i'll try it . thanks