# Class 'DOMDocument' not found error in Ubuntu Laravel

Tags: laravel, email, smtp, laravel-8, html-email

env file parameters:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=<emailadress>
MAIL_PASSWORD=<password>
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

system Features:
PHP 7.4.33
Composer version 1.10.26

I am waiting mail in MailBox. But it is giving error.

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: Error: Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "demo@xxx.com" using 3 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message

Comment: Does any info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42558903/expected-response-code-250-but-got-code-535-with-message-535-5-7-8-username/42558904#42558904) possibly help? Read the comments too, some found other changes that helped as well.